# purescript - modelling a function which throws an exception

Tags: exception, ffi, purescript

Suppose I have a Javascript function `f` which throws an exception.

I'd like to expose it on the Purescript side as

```
foreign import f :: a -> Either e b
```

where `e` is the type of the thrown exception.

I could achieve this by catching the exception and wrapping the result of `f` with the constructors of `Either`, but it seems a dirty solution since I would use Purescript data constructors on the Javascript side.

Is there a better or more standard solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to go about constructing PureScript data from JavaScript is to pass the constructors in as functions. Your JS function would take extra two parameters:

```
// JavaScript
exports.f_ = left => right => a => {
    try { return right(whatever(a)); }
    catch(e) { return left(e); }
}
```

Then in PureScript you import the function, but do not export it to the consumers. Instead, make a wrapper that passes the `Left` and `Right` constructors, and export *that*:

```
-- PureScript
module MyModule(f) where

foreign import f_ :: forall a b e. (e -> Either e b) -> (b -> Either e b) -> a -> Either e b

f :: forall a e b. a -> Either e b
f = f_ Left Right
```

Comment: I only want to complement Fyodor response with a link to the docs: https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/guides/FFI-Tips.md#avoid-directly-calling-ps-code-from-foreign-modules

Comment: I know this is a year and a half later, but the signature of the foreign import can be made more general by replacing the ```Either e b``` with just a single type variable: ```foreign import f_ :: forall a b e r. (e -> r) -> (b -> r) -> a -> r```

Comment: That's technically true @Sledge, but in my experience doing that leads to a lot of confusion among newcomers to the codebase. Having `Either e b` in there isn't technically necessary, but it serves as documentation.